# Automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, finitely-generated, geometric-group-theory, semidirect-product

Let  $M$ be a matrix in $ \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, are there any books/articles that give a description of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes_M\mathbb{Z})$?

According to [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/26/6/543/400922?redirectedFrom=PDF), the automorphism group of any polycyclic group is isomorphic to a linear group.  I am trying to understand how the automorphism group is embedded into the matrix group. I was wondering if anybody has invested this particular example $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes_M\mathbb{Z})$ and gave a description of this group.

Thank you!

Comment: This depends a lot on the matrix $M$. For example, if $M=I_2$ then $G \cong {\mathbb Z}^3$ and ${\rm Aut}(G) \cong {\rm GL}(3, {\mathbb Z})$. Do you want to exclude that case? You might also want to consider the case when $G$ is nilpotent separately.

Comment: Sounds like a very interesting question to me. You could try Merzljakov's method (Ju. I. Merzljakov, Integer representation of the holomorphs of polycyclic
groups, (Russian) Algebra i Logika 9 (1970), 539-558.) or the more modern method stated by Grunewald and Baues ([Automorphism groups of polycyclic-by-finite groups and arithmetic groups](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_2006__104__213_0/))

Comment: @DerekHolt, Thank you. yes, I would like to find $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes_M\mathbb{Z})$ for a general $ M \in  \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$. I am indeed interested in the case when $G$ is virtually nilpotent (i.e. when all the eigenvalues of $M$ are roots of unity).

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is not virtually unipotent (i.e. has trace $\neq 0,\pm 1,\pm 2$), then the normal $\mathbf{Z}^2$ is the nilpotent radical (aka Fitting subgroup) and hence is preserved by automorphisms. Suppose so.

Say an automorphism is positive if the induced automorphism of $\mathbf{Z}$ (obtained after modding out the normal $\mathbf{Z}^2$) is identity. Such an automorphism acts on the normal $\mathbf{Z}$ as some element $M'$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ commuting with $M$. Conversely such $M'$ induces a positive automorphism $(v,n)\mapsto (M'v,n)$.

Hence, letting $A_+$ be the group of positive automorphisms, we have $A_+=C\ltimes A_+^1$, where $C$ is the centralizer of $M$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, and $A_+^1$ consists of those positive automorphisms acting as identity on $\mathbf{Z}^2$. The latter is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^2$ (inside which the image of $\mathrm{Id}_2-M$ consists of inner automorphisms), while $C$ contains the group of inner automorphisms $\langle M\rangle$ with finite index. The group $C$ is itself infinite cyclic.

There are negative automorphisms if and only if $M$ is conjugate to $M^{-1}$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. I don't know if it is always the case (they are indeed conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$).

---

The remaining cases: - when $M$ has infinite order, i.e., $M$ is either unipotent nontrivial, or the negative thereof. Up to conjugation it means that $M= \pm u_k$, $u_k=\begin{pmatrix}1 & k\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. - when $M$ has finite order (1,2,3,4, or 6).

In the case where 1 is not an eigenvalue, then the derived subgroup has finite index in $\mathbf{Z}^2$, and $\mathbf{Z}^2$ can be obtained as inverse image of subgroup of torsion elements in the quotient. So we can argue similarly as in the previous case, although the description of $C$ and $A_+$ is a bit different.

Remains the unipotent case. If $M$ is identity the automorphism group is $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$. Otherwise up to conjugation $M=u_k$ for some $k\ge 1$. For $u_1$, the automorphism group is isomorphic to $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})\ltimes \mathbf{Z}^2$. I haven't computed for larger $k$, it's probably similar (although this might slightly change the outer automorphism group).

Comment: Thank you! May I ask what it means for a matrix to be "virtually unipotent" in general?

Comment: A square matrix $M$ of size $n$ is unipotent if $M-I_n$ is nilpotent. It is virtually unipotent if some power$M^k$, $k>0$, is unipotent, or equivalently if all its eigenvalues (in an algebraic closure of the ground field) are root of unity.